# How to wrap a part of text fetched from array of object in a span tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Given a json object as below:

```
const data = [
  {
    id: "text1",
    text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sollicitudin odio a luctus ornare. Pellentesque nisl tis tellus nec, dapibus turpis. In hac habitasse platea vitae.",
  },
];
```

If I want to include part of text fetched inside a `<span>` tag such as:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum <span>dolor sit amet</span>. </p>
```

How do I do this?

Comment: how do you know which part is to be put in the span ?

Comment: Hi @JiaSH , thanks for coming forward. It is the requirement of the project. I was given a mock up where the text that needs to be span is specified.  ATM it is hard coded inside my component but let's say i create a back end and then fetch the data how do i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do your work!

```
    data[0].text.replace("dolor sit amet", "<span>dolor sit amet</span>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, I imagine that you know which text should be put under the span

```
const data = [
  {
    id: "text1",
    text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sollicitudin odio a luctus ornare. Pellentesque nisl tis tellus nec, dapibus turpis. In hac habitasse platea vitae.",
  },
];

const textToSpan = 'dolor sit amet';
```

In this case you can split your string and render with something like this:

```
const aText = data.text.split(textToSpan);

const aTextRender = aText.reduce((result, t) => {
  if (result.length) {
    result.push(<span>{textToSpan}<span>);
  }
  result.push(t);
  return result;
}, [])

return (
  <p>
    {aTextRender}
  <p>
);
```

Code not tested though :o

Comment: thanks for your help mate, the code is working but it is long compare to other solution

Comment: the other solution is returning a text, not a JSX element, but if that fits your need then its good :) (+ its only treating the first occurence)